# tvOS initial data how to get 10.000 rows of data quickly on app launch

Tags: swift, tvos

I'm testing with Swift tvOS atm.
I'm running into a issue and I'm unsure of how to tackle it.
My app has CloudKit database of a 10.000 rows (7.5mb)
Fetching this data from CloudKit takes about 7.5 minutes. (Which is too long to build on each app start or when tvOS has purged the cache).

What would be the best course of action here?

I thought of a few things:

1. Create a sqllite file on of of my remote server and download that to the root of the app so coredata can us it.
2. Put a SQLite file as an on-demand resource (not sure if that's possible or how to do it).
3. Hard-code all the data.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean with "hard code all data"? Isn't this dynamic changeable data? Otherwise why would you download it from a remote server?

Comment: The network lag from CloudKit is killing you. Try fetching in small amounts, say top 25 (in whatever order of your choosing), and then another 25 as the users scrolls to the bottom of the list.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing your data is a kind of reference database that doesn't change often but does have an update life cycle nonetheless.  I would suggest creating a denormalized list of keys and downloading only that initially as placeholders in your local data structures (memory, cache, or other).  You can then request an asynchronous download from CloudKit to fetch the rest of the data in the background and do "on demand" short queries for data that you need to actually display/use at a given moment.

If you have any usage patterns that can allow you to predict which piece of data you will be needing in the near future, that can also be used to pre-fetch the information more efficiently. This could mean including a bit more than the key in the initial download so you'll need to see where you can strike the best balance.